# How to make custom week1,week2,week3,week4,weekNth in database depending on dates given?

Tags: database, ms-access

```
Employee_Table

eid mydate       Late
1   01/01/2018   2
1   01/02/2018   0
1   01/03/2018   30
1   01/04/2018   4
1   01/05/2018   0
1   01/06/2018   0
1   01/07/2018   3
1   01/08/2018   0 
1   01/09/2018   3
1   01/010/2018  2
1   01/011/2018  10

Select sum(late) as lates from  Employee_Table 
where mydate between '01/01/2018' AND '01/07/2018'    
Group by eid

week1 - 36
week2 - 18
week3 - 00
week4 - 00
week5 - 00
```

This is my problem. How to make a query that is starting from week 1 up week Nth week depending on Date given and the that should start on sunday.

If the first date didn't fall on sunday date end of that should end on saturday

```
week 1 january 01 - 06
week 2 january 07 - 13
week 3 january 14 - 20
week 4 january 21 - 27
week 5 january 28 - 31

Select ?
 as week1 
 as week2
 as week3
 as week4
 as week5
 as weekNth

 from  Employee_Table 
where mydate between '01/01/2018' AND '01/31/2018'
```

Comment: You should use `DATEPART` function  on your date column (in your case `mydate`) with `wk` as week argument (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments)

Comment: What is your database - MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: If the date is part way though the week do you want the entire week or just the part referenced?

Comment: You are grouping by eid, however you don't have this as an output field, or one that is filtered to a specific eid. This will make it hard in the results to map it to a eid.

Comment: Please refrain from tagging multiple RDBMSes. This question deserves an entirely different approach in MySQL, Access or SQL server. I'm removing Access since the between is incorrect for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's [WEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function to determine the current week. So your SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT WEEK(mydate), SUM(lates)
FROM Employee_Table
GROUP BY WEEK(mydate)
```

If you want the exact output you specified, i.e. "weekX" for the week number:

```
SELECT CONCAT('week', WEEK(mydate)), SUM(lates)
FROM Employee_Table
GROUP BY WEEK(mydate)
```

Comment: note when using this mysql date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: @danblack Good point, but I'm assuming OP's dates are in native MySQL format (YYYY-MM-DD), despite the example that seems to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Week definition by default starts with Sunday so you can check if you have a different configuration or not by checking

```
select @@DATEFIRST
```

If it returns 7, then the first day of week is Sunday 
It is possible to change this by using following [FIRSTDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command on SQL Server

```
SET DATEFIRST
```

Maybe you can use following solution on SQL Server where I use [CTE expression](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) (I'm not sure MySQL support CTE) and a [SQL numbers table](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-tsql-cte-numbers-table.aspx)

```
declare @d1 date = '01/01/2018'
declare @d2 date = '12/31/2018'
;with cte as (
    select datepart(wk, @d2) as n
), agg as (
    Select
        eid,
        datepart(wk, mydate) as dp, 
        sum(late) as lates 
    from Employee_Table
    where 
        mydate between @d1 AND @d2
    Group by 
        eid,
        datepart(wk, mydate)
)
Select 
    i, eid, lates
from dbo.NumbersTable(1,datepart(wk, @d2),1) as nt
left join agg
    on i = dp
order by i, eid
```